# Send variables by using $_GET in php mvc

Tags: php, html

My route:

```
class Route
{
    static function start()
    {
        $controller_name = 'add_task';
        $action_name = 'index';

        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
        {   
            $controller_name = $routes[1];
        }
        if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
        {
            $action_name = $routes[2];
        }
        $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
        $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
        $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

        $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
        $model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
        if(file_exists($model_path))
        {
            include "application/models/".$model_file;
        }
        $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
        $controller_path = "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
        if(file_exists($controller_path))
        {
            include "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
        }
        else
        {
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        }

        $controller = new $controller_name;
        $action = $action_name;

        if(method_exists($controller, $action))
        {
            $controller->$action();
        }
        else
        {
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        }
    }
```

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My controller:

```
<?php

class Controller_tasks extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model_tasks();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    function action_index()
    {   
        if (isset($_GET['page'])){
            $data = $this->model->get_data_from_server($_GET['page']);
        }
        else{
            $data = $this->model->get_data_from_server($page = 1);
        }

        $this->view->generate('tasks_view.php', 'template_view.php', $data);
    }
}
```

My part of view:

```
<a href="tasks?page=2">&larr; Back</a>
```

What I need to do to send the page number? How to implement this in mvc?
My route can get only the action name, but not the variable. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I think you need to keep the existing query string using the Query String Append flag [QSA] in your htaccess file

Comment: @Andreas I do not know how to do it, but thx for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use something very very similar. However I go one stage further when splitting the URL on slashes, I assign all further sections as variables, which are then passed to the function as parameters.

I'll show the full code however the bit you're really interested in is within the split URL function.

```
<?php
namespace Core;
use Core\Face\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    /** @var null The bundle */
    private $bundle = null;
    /** @var null The controller */
    private $controller = null;
    /** @var null The method (of the above controller), often also named "action" */
    private $action = null;
    /** @var array URL parameters */
    private $params = array();
    function getBundle()
    {
        return $this->bundle;
    }
    function getController()
    {
        return $this->controller;
    }
    function getAction()
    {
        return $this->action;
    }
    function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
    function setBundle($bundle)
    {
        $this->bundle = ucfirst(strtolower($bundle)); // The bundle
    }
    function setController($controller)
    {
        $this->controller = ucfirst(strtolower($controller)) . "Controller"; // The controller we want.
    }
    function setAction($action)
    {
        $this->action = ucfirst(strtolower($action)) . "Action"; // The action within the controller we want.
    }
    function setParams($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params; // These become variables passed straight into the controller.
    }
    /**
     * "Start" the application:
     * Analyze the URL elements and calls the according controller/method or the fallback
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->getClass($this->splitUrl($request));
    }
    public function getClass()
    {
        $namespace = "{$this->getBundle()}"\\Controller
        if (class_exists($namespace)) { // Namespace exists, and method found.
            $class = new $namespace;
            // check for method: does such a method exist in the controller ?
            if (method_exists($class, $this->getAction())) {
                return call_user_func_array(array($class, $this->getAction()), $this->getParams());
            } elseif (method_exists($class, "indexAction")) {
                return call_user_func(array($class, "indexAction"));
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");
            }
        } else { // Else show index page
            return (new \IndexController())->indexAction();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get and split the URL
     */
    public function splitUrl(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->query->get('url')) {
            // split URL
            $url = explode('/', filter_var(trim($request->query->get('url'), '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            // Put URL parts into according properties
            $this->setBundle(@$url[0]);
            $this->setController(@$url[1]);
            $this->setAction(@$url[2]);
            // Remove controller and action from the split URL
            unset($url[0], $url[1], $url[2]);
            // Rebase array keys and store the URL params
            $this->setParams(array_values($url));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the method in your view instead of using:

`<a href="tasks?page=2">&larr; Back</a>`

It would be:

`<a href="tasks/2">&larr; Back</a>`

Which you can pick up in the corresponding function as so:

```
class Pages { // Or what ever your class/controller is. 
    public function tasks($page = 1){ // Set a default for good measure.
        print $page; // Using the example this would be 2
    }
}
```

The .htaccess is here: https://github.com/BonnieDoug/DougHayward/blob/master/.htaccess

You can also get the code I pasted here from my GitHub here: https://github.com/BonnieDoug/DougHayward/blob/master/Application/Core/Router.php

Comment: What this row do: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] ?

Comment: As close as matters the same as the following 2 lines do in your code, just in one line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
` and `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`